# Getting data from a row in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, rows

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
    {
        if (excelFile != null)
        {
            /* Snip for brevity. */
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "results");
            DataTable data = ds.Tables["results"];

            var people = new List<Person>();

            foreach (var row in data.Rows)
            {
                Person newPerson = new Person(){
                    Id = row?,
                    Name = row?,
                    LastName = row?,
                    DateOfBirth = row?
                };

                people.Add(newPerson);
            }

            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Upload");                      
    }
```

How can I retrieve the information contained in my datatable? I've checked the MSDN docs but they seem to only display how to programatically **create** a new DataTable and not how to retrieve data.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `row.Field<DateTime>("DateOfBirth")`.

Comment: I'm getting compiler errors when running with this approach. *Instance argument: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Data.DataRow'* Any ideas?

Comment: It was because I cannot use var in the foreach loop. I must be explicit and use **foreach DataRow in x.Rows**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Person newPerson = new Person(){
                    Id = (int)row["Id"],
                    Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                    LastName = row["LastName"].ToString(),
                    DateOfBirth = (DateTime)row["DateOfBirth"]
                };
```

Comment: The row variable in the foreach would have to be DataRow, though, correct?

Comment: @Jon: Correct. It has to be a DataRow.